# Local Variable and Global Variable with same name

Tags: java, c++, c

I have two variables, one which is local in a function and the other global. These two variables have the same name. During compilation, I have no errors. So when the code is running, and I use this variable, which one is chosen?

Thank you.

Comment: *during compilation* in which language??? (C, C++ or Java)

Comment: Why don't you just try it and find out?

Comment: C/C++ has recursive scope where each block creates a new scope whose identifiers shadow the outer scope. You can have `int a = 0; void foo(int b) { int a = 1; /* shadows global a */ { int a = 2; int b = 2; /* shadows outer a and b */ { int a = 3; int b = 3; /* shadows outer a and b */ } } }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The local variable will always hide (*shadow*) the "global" one.

In Java, you can access to an instance variable by using the keyword `this`. This is often used in constructors. For example:

```
private String someVar;

public ClassName(String someVar) {
    this.someVar = someVar; // this.someVar is the instance variable
                            // someVar is the local variable
}
```

Comment: But OP is asking about global variables, so the examples (at least the C++ one) seem irrelevant.

Comment: What does that "hide(shadow)" mean? Will the local variable be accessed or the Global one. In C/C++, the local variable will be accessed. In C++ you can use the scope resolution operator(::) to access the global variable.

Answer (score 2):

The local variable shadows over the global variable.
i.e, unless you explicitly specify that you are using a global variable, the local variable with the same name will be used in the function.